# Data and methods in a class

Tags: class, object

As far as I'm aware, data and actions "gets packaged" into its own object.

Imagine the situation where my program contains 2 objects.

Object1 has data1 and method1.

Object2 has its data and method as well.

But what if object2's method is IDENTICAL as method1? Does that mean method1 needs to be copied and relabelled as method2, then "packaged" into object2?

If so, that defeats the whole purpose of not having to duplicate code.

On the other hand, if object2 can somehow use method1 (either directly or indirectly), that contradicts the "each object is self-contained" principle.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What is the context of the question?

Comment: I'm trying to understand OO concepts.